# Python enviroment os independant requirements

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

im using [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) guide to generate a python-environment.

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

and then

```
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

There are some windows-specific packages that I use but do not want to be in the requirements.txt. Is there a way to acive this?

```
pywin32==228
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
```

if not, can i install and ignore those modules, since the installation process will always stop at pywin and will not install the packages that come afterwards.

Comment: Noone can tell if the program you are developing on is OS dependent or not. That depends on your implementation.  
You should develop in a `venv` (virtual python environment) and only install dependencies you need. Then you can generate a new clean `requirements.txt` however whether you are still getting e.g. windows dependent dependencies depends on what your project depends on.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Environment Markers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#environment-markers) in your `requirements.txt`

```
pywin32==228; platform_system=="Windows"
```

Comment: Is there a way of adding these markers using `pip freeze`? As far as I can tell there's not - but posting in hope there might be!